# Writing parsers with Text.ParserCombinators

Tags: parsing, haskell

In class, we wrote parsers by defining our own Parser type and this gave us a lot of flexibility. For example, if we wanted to make code and parse out "[at]" as '@', we could write

```
atParser = Parser $ \s ->
    case s of
        w:x:y:z:zs ->
            | (w:x:y:z:[]) == "[at]" = ['@',zs]
            | otherwise = []
        zs -> []
```

However, I cannot figure out how to implement this sort of parser using Text.ParserCombinators. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [`string` combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:string).

```
λ> :set -package parsec
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...

λ> import Text.Parsec

λ> :t string
string :: Stream s m Char => String -> ParsecT s u m String

λ> parse (string "[at]") "" "[at]"
Right "[at]"

λ> parse (string "[at]") "" "[at"
Left (line 1, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting "[at]"

λ> parse ('@' <$ string "[at]") "" "[at]"
Right '@'
```